# Switch audio between USB devices on Android

Tags: android, audio, usb

I have two USB headphones / speakers attached to my Android device. I can list them with:

```
UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
Map<String, UsbDevice> deviceMap = filterAudioOnly(usbManager.getDeviceList());
```

I cannot see a way to specifically select a `UsbDevice` for Android to use. So I was trying to effectively disable the device I don't want to use by claiming it:

```
UsbDeviceConnection connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
    UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(i);
    connection.claimInterface(intf, true);
}
```

If another app is playing music whilst I do this, the music stops coming out of the device I have claimed and continues through the device I haven't: great. However, by releasing the interface with:

```
for (UsbInterface intf: interfaces) {
    connection.releaseInterface(intf);
}
connection.close();
```

Does not re-enable the audio through that device.

I also tried only targeting the output endpoint of the UsbDevice interface, but that was even less successful.

Is there something else I should be trying?